# Flutter: refresh state

Tags: flutter, dart, mobile, setstate

i am new in flutter and stuck with this issue. How can I update a widget from another script using the onTap method? I tried using setState() but I keep getting an error. I am using FutureBuilder and GridView.builder. Right now I'm just getting all the records from the table. I wanted to update by category id. Please help me.

```
class ItemsWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  ItemsPage createState() => ItemsPage();
  
}

class ItemsPage extends State<ItemsWidget> {

  static var catId = 0;
  late Future<List<Item>> items;

  Future<List<Item>> fetchItems(int category) async {
  final response =
      await http.get(Uri.parse('http://10.0.2.2:8000/api/v1/productList/'));

  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    List<dynamic> list = json.decode(response.body);
    var it = list.map((item) => Item.fromJson(item)).toList();
    if (category == 0){
    List<Item> items = list.map((item) => Item.fromJson(item)).toList();
    return items;
    }else{
    List<Item> items = it.where((item) => item.category == category).toList();
    return items;
    }
  } else {
    throw Exception('Error');
  }
}

  @override
  void initState() {
    print(catId);
    items = fetchItems(catId);
    print("fetch");
    super.initState();
  }

  static String utf8convert(String text) {
    List<int> bytes = text.toString().codeUnits;
    return utf8.decode(bytes);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder<List<Item>>(
        future: items,
        builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<List<Item>> snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
            return const Center(
              child: CircularProgressIndicator(
                color: Colors.deepPurpleAccent,
              ),
            );
          }
          if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
            if (snapshot.hasError) {
              return Center(
                child: Text(
                  'An ${snapshot.error} occurred',
                  style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 18, color: Colors.red),
                ),
              );
            } else if (snapshot.hasData) {
              return GridView.builder(
               ...
            );
            }
            ;
          };

          return const Center(
            child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
          );
        });
```

Comment: What is the error you are getting?  What does the ... code in the GridView.builder look like?

Comment: If I add setState to the current class it works. But if I try to call setState from a class in another script, I get an error - "FlutterError (setState() called in constructor: ItemsPage#29381(lifecycle state: created, no widget, not mounted)...".

Comment: Yes, you should only call setState from the State class for a StatefulWidget.  If an action in a child widget needs to trigger the setState method of a parent widget, you could pass the child widget a callback function. (see https://samed-harman.medium.com/flutter-widget-communication-with-callbacks-flutter-3-dart-2-17-48c60d389161) or you could use some other form of state management such as RiverPod or FlutterBloc.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you want to call fetchItems from another screen. In that case you can take the function outside ItemsPage and make a let's say someAPI class . Then you will be able to call that function from this page as someAPI.fetchItems(catId) and get the results. You can do the same on other screen as well

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).